# Ionic Corodva: Project not working after upgrade

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Please I need you to help me to get out of the dark here.
I successfully built a project using intel xdk on ionic Cordova framework. My project was working perfectly but all at a sudden I saw an unprade notification to upgrade my intel xdk plugin. Immediately after I did, all of my projects stopped working on the device but working on the emulator.
I have tried all possible but no head way. Please kindly assist with any suggestions.
Thanks in anticipation!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update by JesseMonroy650 is a welcome development. But after hours of battle this is my solution.
I added CSP at the header of index.html and this is it

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Take not of the script-src *. 
Thereafter

```
Cordova build android
```

and

```
Cordova run android
```

Looks weird, but that was my answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem too.
then i run these commands:

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install npm -g
```

then reinstall ionic cordova

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

hope it works for you too..